# data fetch with ajax and laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

```
 public function show_offers(Request $request){
                if($request->ajax()){
                    $all_jobs=Job_offer::all();
                    return response()->json($all_jobs);       
                 }
            }
```

i have controller return all_jobs in json format.
 in my html i want to display the name of category related with the catagory_id in all_jobs variable 
i have tried this but it just returned category_id=9  wish i want to display the category name associated with

```
 <script> 
      $(document).on('keyup','.form-control',function(){
        var root = "job_listing";
        $.ajax({
          url: root,      
          method: 'GET',
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(response){

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                console.log(response[i].category_id)  
                $('.job').html(response[i].offer_title);
                $('.location').html(response[i].location_id);

                }

          }

        })
      });
    </script>
```

job offer table structure

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('job_offer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('employer_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('location_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('salary_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('experience_id');


            $table->foreign('employer_id')->references('id')->on('employers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');;
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');;
            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');;
            $table->foreign('salary_id')->references('id')->on('salaries')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');;
            $table->foreign('experience_id')->references('id')->on('experience')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');;

            $table->string('offer_title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('type_emploi');
            $table->string('offer_image');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Pls share your table structure

Comment: @Sehndev  ok i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your JobOffer.php model file

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Then in your controller try below code:

```
$all_jobs=Job_offer::with('category')->all();
```

Then in Ajax Try accessing this data with this will get your category name:

```
response[i].category.name
```

here name is the field name of your category table which contains the name of the category.

Comment: thank you it worked fine with $all_jobs=Job_offer::with('category')->get();

Comment: @MoussaEloifi Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information